# How to create an object in react native?

Tags: react-native

I just started learning react native and I am having issues with creating an object. Here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class object {
    name: 'joe'
    age: 27
    country: 'France'
}
```

And when I try to instantiate it in another class like this

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
    } from 'react-native';

    import object from './object.js'

    export default class MyComponent extends Component {

      var man = new Object();

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{man.age}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    })
```

I get a syntax error Unexpected token var ->man = new Object(). How do I fix this?

Comment: Since you are trying to add an instance variable `man` to the `MyComponent` class, you don't need the `var` with it. That is the unexpected token pointed out.

Comment: You could declare "var man = new Object()"  within your render function before your return. However, it should be noted using "new Object()" creates a new blank object and won't contain the info from your object.js file. You might want to take a look at this for creating your "object" class: https://javascript.info/constructor-new. So instead, something like "function Man() { this.name = 'joe'; this.age = 27; this.country = 'France'; } export default man = new Man()", depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @swimisbell I change it to 

`import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {

  View,

  Text,

  StyleSheet,

} from 'react-native';

function Man() {

    this.name = 'joe';

    this.age = 27;

    this.country = 'France';

}

export default object = new Man();`

And I get "undefined is not an object"

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake: change `export default object = new Man()` to `const object = new Man(); export default object;`
That should export correctly. And because you are creating and exporting a new Man() object from your .object file now, you don't need to use `var man = new Object()` then `man.age` in your MyComponent file, you can simply say `object.age` to get the properties instead. (Though I'd suggest renaming 'object' and calling it 'man' instead to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your object in typescript file(object.ts) for exemple:

```
 export class object {
   name: 'joe',
   age: 27,
   country: 'France'

   constructor(obj) {
     this.name=obj.key; 
     this.age=obj.nom; 
     this.country=obj.prenom; 
   }       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the wrong part is you export default **class** object, FYI: **CLASS** is not **OBJECT**

the correct using of export is

```
export const object = {
    name: 'joe',
    age: 27,
    country: 'France'
}
```

then you can import it with

```
import {object} from './object.js'
```

Comment: FYI: *CLASS* is a class declaration word, and `class object {...}` is creating a class named "object"

Comment: that is the wrong part dude you should create variable and make it to object, not make a **CLASS** named object @KirillGlazunov